# Copying structure of a list of list to a flat list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists as follows.

```
l1=[a,b,c,d,e]
l2=[[p,q],[r,s,t]]
```

How do I create a list of lists from l1 similar to list l2 ?

Desired output:
[[a,b],[c,d,e]]

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise here with what you want. What does it mean to have "similar" structure? Is it always 5 elements, 2 in one list and 3 in the other?

Comment: Will `l2` have some arbitrary structure?

Comment: why `[[a,b],[c,d,e]]` ? Why not `[[a,b,c],[d,e]]` or `[[a],[b,c,d,e]]`, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach will work for arbitrarily nested lists, and doesn't require a deep copy nor an inefficient `pop` from the end of the list, making this version linear on the total number of items, instead of quadratic:

```
def structured_replace(values, nested):
    it = iter(values)
    def _helper(nested):
        return [
            _helper(item) if isinstance(item, list) else next(it)
            for item in nested
        ]
    return _helper(nested)

a, b, c, d, e = "abcde"
p, q, r, s, t = "pqrst"
l1 = [a,b,c,d,e]
l2 = [[p,q],[r,s,t]]
print(structured_replace(l1, l2))
```

Also, just for fun, here's an iterative solution:

```
def structured_replace(values, nested):
    it = iter(values)
    top_result = []
    stack = [(nested, top_result)]
    while stack:
        item, result = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(item, list):
            subresult = []
            result.append(subresult)
            for sub in reversed(item):
                stack.append((sub, subresult))
        else:
            result.append(next(it))
    return top_result[0]
```

Also, here's a *breadth-first* approach, which we can modify the iterative approach easily and use the standard queue-based approach:

```
def structured_replace_breadth_first(values, nested):
    from collections import deque
    it = iter(values)
    top_result = []
    stack = deque([(nested, top_result)])
    while stack:
        item, result = stack.popleft()
        if isinstance(item, list):
            subresult = []
            result.append(subresult)
            for sub in item:
                stack.append((sub, subresult))
        else:
            result.append(next(it))
    return top_result[0]
```

For the differences:

```
In [5]: structured_replace('abcdefg', [[1, 2], 3, [4, [5, 6], 7]])
Out[5]: [['a', 'b'], 'c', ['d', ['e', 'f'], 'g']]

In [6]: structured_replace_level_first('abcdefg', [[1, 2], 3, [4, [5, 6], 7]])
Out[6]: [['b', 'c'], 'a', ['d', ['f', 'g'], 'e']]
```

Comment: interestingly iit is easy to generalize to structure composed of list or tuple. for instance in your first solution by 1/testing for list and tuple, 2/optionally converting the list comprehension to  a generator, and 3/wrapping the return value in a cast 'type(nested)()'

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach: use `deepcopy(l2)` to create the structure of the new list, and then recursively traverse it and replace its non-list items with items taken from a copy of `l1`.

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e = "abcde"
>>> p, q, r, s, t = "pqrst"
>>> l1=[a,b,c,d,e]
>>> l2=[[p,q],[r,s,t]]
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> l3 = deepcopy(l2)
>>> def deep_replace(l1, l2):
...     for i, item in enumerate(l2):
...         if isinstance(item, list):
...             deep_replace(l1, item)
...         else:
...             l2[i] = l1.pop(0)
...
>>> deep_replace(l1.copy(), l3)
>>> l3
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

This should work with arbitrarily deep lists (up to Python's recursion limit anyway).

If preserving the original `l1` and `l2` isn't important, you can skip the `copy` and `deepcopy` calls.

Comment: Nice.. Missing `return l2`. Would n't it be convenient to make the copy/deepcopy in deep_replace.

Comment: @hpchavaz you don't need a `return`, this approach mutates the inputs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. ok, I see.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty list to store the result, and a `count` variable to store the start index for each sub-list, then for each sublist in `l2`, get the size of the sublist, and take the items from list `l1`

```py
res = []
count = 0
for sub in l2:
    res.append(l1[count:len(sub)+count])
    count += len(sub)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
res
Out[79]: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrarily deep structures, does it?

Comment: @Samwise, Absolutely not, but OP hasn't mentioned it either. For deeply nested structure, I think recursion can be applied.